# ng-click while having href for fallback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular allows you to ignore `href` when using `ng-click`:

```
<a href ng-click="openModal()">Open modal</a>
```

But this is not suitable when you want to generate HTML snapshot for SEO or a PDF with active links.

Is there a way to have the following logic for this markup:

```
<a href="/modal" ng-click="openModal()">Open modal</a>
```

if ng-click is not available, use href action (at the moment href action will override ng-click)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd wrap it in a directive inside which I'd call preventDefault to prevent the default behaviour of the link element:

```
app.directive("myLinkOverload", function () {
    return function (scope, element) {
        element.on("click", function (evt) {           
            evt.preventDefault();
        });
    }
});

<a href="/modal" ng-click="openModal()" data-my-link-overload="">Open modal</a>
```